# Не работает форма на php Ajax Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap, форма

Здравствуйте, я по инструкции собрал Ajax форму которая обрабатывает данные в БД  (удаляет редактирует и тд), после того как я собрал эту форму все просто отлично работало!

В общем начал я ее делать под себя в самой форме было 2 поле на обработку + id, я переименовал все эти поля и сменил таблицу все также хорошо работало, но как только я добавил еще 8 полей тут же все крякнуло! Как я понял проблема в операторах если я не ошибаюсь, скажу сразу я не великой спец может проблема и не проблема, но не для меня.

Выкладываю кусок кода в котором проблема, если что потом докину остальное.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var offersid = $('#offers_id').val();
    var offersname = $('#offers_name').val();
    var offersamount = $('#offers_amount').val();
    var offersсonditionspercent = $('#offers_сonditions_percent').val();
    var offersсonditionsno_percent = $('#offers_сonditions_no_percent').val();
    var offersсonditionsterm = $('#offers_сonditions_term').val();
    var offersсonditionsage = $('#offers_сonditions_age').val();
    var offerstype = $('#offers_type').val();
    var offerslink_id = $('#offers_link_id').val();
    var extension = $('#user_image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if(extension != '')
    {
        if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
        {
            alert("Invalid Image File");
            $('#user_image').val('');
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(offersid != '' && offersname != '')
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
            method:'POST',
            data:new FormData(this),
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#user_form')[0].reset();
                $('#userModal').modal('hide');
                dataTable.ajax.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Both Fields are Required");
    }
});
```

ошибка вроде в строке

```
if(offersid != '' && offersname != '')
```

Выше над этой строй остальные строчки которые надо добавить но у меня не выходи.
Если кто знаком с этим подскажите, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Решено, проблема была в длинных названиях страниц
*offers_сonditions_percent
offers_сonditions_no_percent
offers_сonditions_term
offers_сonditions_age*
я не знаю почему но все из-за них!